# parse Json with filed containing html, escape character & new line code

Tags: python, json

I am trying to extract below JSON into csv file, it failed to parse field "questionLBL" because of escape char,\n,".I have tried replace also but it didn't helped much.

Can anyone please help me to parse this JSON?

```
{
   "question": {
       "active": true,
       "itemId": "746",
       "alternative": null,
       "searchTerm": null,
       "answer": "50000",
       "enumerationCodeDelimiters": null,
       "dataType": "String",
       "multiValued": false,
       "smId": "0778299",
       "workType": "REQUEST",
       "type": "External",
       "totalQuestions": "23",
       "Label": "Request Form",
       "questionLBL": "Request Type\n<em style=\"color: rgb(255, 0, 0); font-family: Arial, Verdana, sans-serif; font-size: 13px;\">If you are unsure which request type to use, please see the attached Reference file.</em>"
    }}
```

I have tried many other way one of the example:

```
import json
import csv
import sys
reload(sys)
sys.setdefaultencoding("utf-8")
with open("test_2020.json", "r") as rf:
    decoded_data = json.load(rf)

#print(decoded_data)
# Check is the json object was loaded correctly
try:
 with open("test.csv","w") as outfile:
    f = csv.writer(outfile,delimiter='|',quoting=csv.QUOTE_ALL)

    for i in decoded_data:
     
      f.writerow([i.get(("active"),"null"),i.get(("itemId"),"null"),i.get(("alternative"),"null")\
      i.get(("searchTerm"),"null") ,i.get(("answer"),"null"),\
      i.get(("enumerationCodeDelimiters"),"null"),i.get(("dataType"),"null"),i.get(("multiValued"),"null"),\
      i.get(("smId"),"null"),i.get(("workType"),"null")\
      i.get(("type"),"null"),\
      i.get(("totalQuestions"),"null"),i.get(("Label"),"null"),i.get(("questionLBL"),"null"),\
      ])


except KeyError:
      print("Error Found")
```

Comment: Out of curiosity, how did you created such json?

Comment: Through API from crm system